# How to handle a MouseDoubleClick in a cell of a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` in a `WinForm`. The cells of the `TableLayoutPanel` are populated dynamically with custom `UserControls`. Each of this `UserControls` is used to display a `Chart` (with the DevExpress Charting Tools). The reason behind this is to arrange the charts in several rows and each row contains three columns.

Now since the charts are rather small, I want to give the user the opportunity to maximize each chart by double-clicking on the chart. Therefore I tried to use the `MouseDoubleClick-Event`.

I first used the `Designer` to assign the `MouseDoubleClick-Event` to the `TableLayoutPanel`. This works fine as long as the cells of the table are empty. As soon as there is a `UserControl` in it, the event is not fired/captured(?) any more.

I tried to set the event to the whole `UserControl` (in its `Designer-View` by defining its `MouseDouybleClick-Event`). But it is not captured again :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseDoubleClick` event is fired **for the control that is actually double-clicked**.

If you tried to double-click on one of your UserControls, then it's the UserControl that will fire the event.

EDIT:

As your `Chart` control on your UserControl has the `DockStyle` property to `Fill`, then it's actually the `Chart` control that is double-clicked (as your UserControl is not visible at all).

What you could do is to forward the event to the parent control (your UserControl):

YouUserControl.cs:

```
    private void chartControl_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Note:
Actually, it's a bit strange to create a UserControl that only contains one control with `DockStyle.Fill`. What didn't you use the Chart control directly on your `TableLayoutPanel`? If it's because you have additional method/properties in your UserContorl, you may instead want to inherit your UserControl from your `Chart` control (if it's not `sealed`).

Comment: but the event of the UserControl is never fired....i set a breakpoint to check...

Comment: @AlexanderAdrowitzer Did you clicked on the `UserControl`... or on the `Chart` control into the `UserControl`?

Comment: i have two classes: Form1 and UserControl. I have my TableLayout panel and add the UserControl the following way: for (int i = 0; i < 4: i++) {UserControl ctrl = new UserControl(); ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ctrl, 0, i);} Then I click on the shown Controls but nothing happens...

Comment: ah now I understand what you mean! I indeed clicked on the Chart instead of the UserControl and did not set the event to the Chart. Now everything works fine!! thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexanderAdrowitzer You might want to [accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if everything is OK, so other people will know your problem is now solved.